# Esper EQL check if attribute is set

Tags: java, esper

Let's say we have the following statement:

```
String STATEMENT =
            "SELECT" +
                    " l.address.locality," +
            " FROM" +
                    " Location AS l";
```

There could be the case now that address is null. How can I tell Esper not to inform my subscriber in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT address.locality FROM Location(address is not null)`